# Preventing row change when a database error encountered

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview, row

**Situation:**

I'm developing a winforms application with C# in VS2013.

I have a datagridview bound to a MySQL table through a DataAdapter.  Row validation and database updating takes place whenever a user clicks away from an edited row to a new row.  Row validation is handled in RowValidat**ing** and dataadapter.Update is handled in RowValidat**ed**.

**Issue:**

Where validation errors occur in RowValidat**ing** then I can use Cancel = true to stop the update and keep the row in error as the current selection.  However validation can also fail when the database gets updated (e.g. where database constraints or concurrency prevent update).  I can trap these but, as I'm now in RowValidat**ed**, Cancel = true is no longer available.  As a result I end up with the old row flagged as an error but selection has moved on to the new row.

**Question:**

Is there some way of abandoning further processing and in particular the move to a new row once things have progressed as far as an Update in RowValidat**ed**?  Put another way, is there some analogue of Cancel = true in RowValidat**ed**?

Comment: Move `dataadapter.Update` to `RowValidating` event handler after actual row validating passed through. If updating fails, set `Cancel = true` there

Comment: Thanks @Fabio.  Unfortunately when dataadapter.Update gets called in RowValidating it doesn't do anything.  I guess at that stage it assumes that there are no changes to be commited.

Comment: You catch the updated-fails in an exception? you could store the row number before and reset it in the catch..

Comment: @TaW That's what I think I'll end up having to do.  Seems pretty unsatisfactory though.  This whole dgv "update on leaving a row" has just been a nightmare when I would have thought it was bread and butter stuff for .Net.  With much less sophisticated products like MS Access this "just works".

Answer (score 1):

Found a way forward with this at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx.

It says:

> If you have custom validation that takes place after the Validating
>   event, it will not affect the data binding. For example, if you have
>   code in a Validated event that attempts to cancel the data binding,
>   the data binding will still occur. In this case, to perform validation
>   in the Validated event, change the control's Data Source Update Mode
>   property (under (Databindings)(Advanced)) from OnValidation to Never,
>   and add Control.DataBindings[""].WriteValue() to your
>   validation code.